# How to import a file , where the part of the file name get changes very frequently?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I am trying to import a file , where the part of the file name get changes very frequently. Current date is the part of the file name. so it get changes very frequently.

Below is my code the import the file. since its name changes 
How do I import the file without changing the file name every day ?

> var CusInfo = path.join(__dirname,'
>   CusInfo_2018_05-17.txt');

Comment: Have you considered doing the import by reading the contents of the parent folder?

Comment: Since its name changes and there is a rule for its name, implement the rule in the code to find the name of the file. Don't hardcode its name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of where we use the `fs` library to read the contents of a directory and search for files containing 'CusInfo'.

```
import fs from 'fs';

let contents = fs.readDirSync('./foo');

for(let x = 0; x < contents.length; x++){
 if(contents[x].includes('CusInfo')){
    // Do more checks or use the file or save to another variable.
   }
}
```

Now if the file name changes because of the date you can still find the file or files.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the name of the file you want to read changes every day, you need to describe the same naming rules in your code, if you don't want hardcode the name.

Since (I'm assuming) you just want today's data to be in the path of the `txt` file, just put that into the file name. You can do that with [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) like so:

```
const moment = require('moment');
const fs = require('fs');

const now = moment();
const fileName = `CusInfo_${now.format('YYYY_MM-DD')}.txt`;

fs.readFileSync(fileName);
```

Now this might very well throw an error, because there is no guarantee that the `txt` file have been created yet.

To handle this, use [fs.access()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_access_path_mode_callback) before actually reading the file

```
fs.access(fileName, fs.constants.F_OK, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        fileName = `CusInfo_${now.add(-1, 'days').format('YYYY_MM-DD')}.txt`;
    }

    fs.readFileSync(fileName)
}
```

This code above will check if the `txt` file for today exsists, and if not, will change the file name yesterday `txt`file.